# Limiting total size of result with C++20 fmt

Tags: c++, c++20, fmt

I know I can limit the size of a particular string argument, but IDK how to do it for the entire output.
In other words can [this](https://godbolt.org/z/dqJE4p) program be written with only one call to format?

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <fmt/format.h>

int LOG_MAX_MESSAGE_LENGTH = 11;

void f(const char* p) {
    std::cout << fmt::format("{:.{}}", fmt::format("ABI is {}", p),
                             LOG_MAX_MESSAGE_LENGTH)
              << std::endl;
}

int main() {
    f("hellooooo");
}
```

Comment: Can you not just format it into a string and crop out the extra stuff?

Comment: Yes, but I prefer to have something nicer if it can be done. And I know that nicer is subjective so please let's not start flame wars about if str.resize(std::min(LOG_MAX_MESSAGE_LENGTH, str.size()) is ugly or not... for me it is ugly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's also `format_to_n`, which takes an output iterator and a size (and then the usual format string and arguments).

```
format_to_n(
    std::ostream_iterator(std::cout), LOG_MAX_MESSAGE_LENGTH,
    "ABI is {}", p);
```

Comment: can it work with a string(in case I do not want to output it, but preserve output in std::string).?

Comment: @NoSenseEtAl Sure, it takes any output iterator - just provide an output iterator that outputs to a `std::string`.

Comment: @NoSenseEtAl, yes, `format_to_n` can work with any output iterator. To append to a string use `back_inserter(s)`.

Comment: @vitaut Oh, what do _you_ know about `fmt`? :-) (Hi, Victor!)

Comment: for people wanting an example with std::string https://godbolt.org/z/fKi3tj

Comment: @Barry, hey! Thanks for answering the {fmt}/std::format questions =)

Comment: @vitaut since you are here: was there ever any discussion of enabling this capability with format? I know you do not want to provide overload for evey idea somebody has, but this is quite common( people want to print/show something to user, and they want to limit total size of output(and potentially replace last 3 chars with ...)). Current solution is fine, but I can not make string const and it is 2 line instead of 1. I mostly care about no const 2 lines is fine(and no I do not want to use IIFE :) ).

Comment: No, but you can easily wrap format_to in another function that returns a truncated string.